# Mudando letras em C

Tags: c

estou com uma duvida, to fazendo um algorítimo que pegue a frase do usuário que não tenha sentido, como se fosse um código, para resolver tem um chave que é as letras que mais sai do alfabeto português, para resolver eu tenho que associar cada letra do texto com a letra que mais usada no português, EX c =a, z=o e assim por diante, eu fiz o código só que ele não muda fica sempre a mesma letra que o usuário digitou. alguém poderia me dar umas dicas.`#include

```
#include <string.h>
main()
{
    char chave[20],texto[20],frase[20];
    int size,i;
    printf("Digite o texto para ser alterado: ");
    scanf("%s",chave);
    size=strlen(chave);
    strcpy(texto,chave);  
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if (frase[i]=='c')
            frase[i]='a';
        else if (texto[i]=='b')
            frase[i]='s';
        else if (texto[i]=='d')
            frase[i]='e';
        else if (texto[i]=='e')
            frase[i]='d';
    } 
    printf("Texto original:\n%s\n Novo texto:\n%s\n",chave,texto);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei alguns erros no seu como, por exemplo, `if (frase[i]=='c') frase[i]='a';` e se não me engano você queria assim `if (texto[i]=='c') frase[i]='a';`

Alterei mais algumas coisas no seu código e já está a funcionar.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
main()
{
    char chave[20], texto[20], frase[20];
    int size,i;

    printf("Digite o texto para ser alterado: ");
    scanf("%s",chave);

    size=strlen(chave);
    strcpy(texto, chave);  

    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if (texto[i]=='c')
            frase[i]='a';
        else if (texto[i]=='b')
            frase[i]='s';
        else if (texto[i]=='d')
            frase[i]='e';
        else if (texto[i]=='e')
            frase[i]='d';
        else frase[i]=texto[i];
    } 
    printf("Texto original:\n %s\nNovo texto:\n %s\n", chave, frase);  
}
```

Comment: muito obrigado, não sei pq que quando eu digito C ele aparece D, teria que ser A, mas muito obrigado mesmo.

Comment: Outra duvida que surgiu, como faça para que quando duas letras se repetem na sequencia,  atribuir um peso a elas?

Comment: Desculpe eu não entendi la muito bem, mas tipo, AC = S tipo isso?

Comment: eu que não expliquei bem, de acordo com a chave que são as letras do alfabeto que mais se repetem, EX a, e, cada uma dela aparem um número de vezes, como o A que é 35 vezes o O 16, mas assim fica facil atribuir um valos no texto que eu quero mudar, mas vamos supor que no texto tem uma letra que aparece 11, e no alfabeto essa letra seja o i,p e q por exemplo, como faço para que o programa escolha a letra certa.

Comment: Vamos ver se eu entendi. Então se o utilizador escrever AAAAABB, neste caso temos 5 A então no alfabeto a letra que está na posição 5 é E, então todos esses A vão ser E, ficando EEEEEBB. Bem foi o que eu entendi.

Comment: não digo na posição mas sim o numero de letras que se repetem, exemplo, no alfabeto português a letra que mais se utiliza é o A, a segunda é o E, vamos dizer que tenha uma frase assim rtttxxxyyyrrr, a letra A aparece 4 vezes, então ela vira na na saida do algoritmo, o y 3 como é a segunda que mais aparece ele vira E, até aqui é tranquilo,  só que tenho um problema, como fazer para que as letras ttt e XXX vire a letra correspondente na saída, pois elas aparecem 3 vezes. se puder me da uma dica, to aceitando